# Change dtype of none square numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4])
c = np.array([a, b])
```

c has two `np.ndarrays` inside of different size, when I try to call `c.astype(np.int8)`, I would get a value error of `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`. How can I change `dtype` of c?

Comment: That's happening because `a` and `b` length are different. That way, `c` could never be a 2D matrix. If you set `a` and `b` with same length, `c.astype(np.int8)` will work properly.

Comment: @GabrielMilan Actually, I have a pd.DataFrame, for one column, it stores a list of lists of numbers. Using df.col_name.to_numpy(), I got a ndarray of ndarrays of numbers where each inner ndarray may have different length. I just need those numbers to have a smaller data type int8 instead of int64.

Comment: This way you could just do similar to Adrien answer:  
`np.array(df.col_name, dtype=np.int8)`

Comment: @GabrielMilan, nope, still get the same error, this column does not store numbers, but lists of numbers.

Comment: In your dataframe, the column dtype is `object`.  You can't change that.  But are those individual elements lists or arrays.  You've described them both ways.  If lists, they don't have `dtype`.  If arrays, they can be changed - individually.

Comment: Show the `df.col_name.to_numpy()`, or at least look at it yourself.  See the `dtype` (in the `repr` print)?  See the elements - list or array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `arr` is a numpy array of dtype object containing numpy arrays, you could do:

```
arr8 = np.array([i.astype('int8') for i in arr])
```

Demo:

```
arr = array([array([0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
...        array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
...        array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])],
...       dtype=object)
print(arr)

array([array([0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])],
      dtype=object)

print(np.array([i.astype('int8') for i in arr]))

array([array([0], dtype=int8), array([0, 1], dtype=int8),
       array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int8), array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int8),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int8),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int8),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int8),
       array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int8)], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 3):

To specify the type of your array during the creation, simply use `dtype=xxx`.
Ex:

```
c = np.array([a,b], dtype=object)
```

If you want to change the type from `int64` to `int8`, you could use:

```
a.dtype = np.int8
b.dtype = np.int8
```

Or you can copy `a` and `b`:

```
c = np.array(a, dtype=np.int8)
d = np.array(a, dtype=np.int8)
```

Finally, if you don't have access to `a` and `b` but only to `c`, here how you can do the same:

```
for arr in c:
    arr.dtype = np.int8
```

Comment: Actually, I have a `pd.DataFrame`, for one column, it stores a list of lists of numbers. Using `df.col_name.to_numpy()`, I got a `ndarray` of `ndarrays` of numbers where each inner `ndarray` may have different length. I just need those numbers to have a smaller data type int8 instead of int64.

Comment: I've edited my answer, does it answer your question now?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```py
arr = list()

for row in range(len(df.desired_column)):
  arr.append(np.array(df.desired_column.loc[row], dtype=np.int8))

arr = np.array(arr)
```

This way every element of `arr` will be a numpy array with the desired `dtype`. On this example, `np.int8`.